# Robocopy to a drive connected to a wlan router fails

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, robocopy

I have a wireless router and an USB hard drive connected to it. Basic file access on the command line and Explorer works flawlessly after having set up some options on the router and mapping to some folders with

```
net use k: \\ROUTER\Folder1 /user:MYLAPTOP\Me password /persistent:yes
net use n: \\ROUTER\Folder2 /user:MYLAPTOP\Me password /persistent:yes
```

Robocopy (and using SyncToy for that matter) to a network drive however fails:

```
robocopy c:\Files k:\Backup /MIR /Z
```

gives

```
There is not enough space on the disk.
2010/01/05 09:52:11 ERROR 112 (0x00000070) Accessing Destination Directory N:\
Waiting 30 seconds...
```

The error message is misleading: there is plenty of space on the disk and the folders I'm copying are small. The router is an ASUS WL-500gp with a standard firmware. I'd appreciate if someone would be able to explain what is causing the problem and, if possible, how to fix it.

Comment: Start with the obvious: how much free space is there on the remote disk? Does copying a smaller file work?

Comment: @Richard: There is enough space. I'll edit the question to indicate that.

Answer (score 2):

Logically, the problem is either with the router, or with robocopy, or some unknown glitch in Windows 7.

Try running robocopy with the /Z switch, which is [defined](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) as:

> /Z : Copy files in restartable mode
>   (survive network glitch).

If it works better with this switch than without, then you have an issue with the router not being up to the task.

You may also try [XXCOPY](http://www.xxcopy.com/index.htm), whose author boldly claims that [XXCopy supersedes RoboCopy](http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy30.htm).
If this works better than robocopy, then the problem is with robocopy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if the username and password is tripping up the script command.

When you mapped the drive letter in Explorer, did you actually have to use a username and password to map the drive?  (MYLAPTOP\Me password)

In my experience, if I may a drive under a profile "scott", if I execute a script or command prompt under the profile "scott" I will get all the drive letters I mapped when I was logged in.  (i.e.  When I login and in Explorer map a drive to Z, I can open a command prompt and access Z.  I can also schedule a task putting my username and password in to execute the script and the script can use Z.)

So, I'm wondering if the net use command is not necessary, or if you are using the proper username and password configured in the router to map the drive letter.

I'm not user if I understand how things are configured, so I hope these tips help.

Comment: I had to do the mapping only once and it persists flawlessly. I suppose there is something fishy going on on the router: it allows files to be copied and deleted, but doesn't allow changes in file permissions or changing the dates. Maybe some day I'll install a custom firmware and try again...

Comment: I'm curious if you can upload a file to the router's hard drive via Explorer's mapped drive letter, then from a command prompt pull it down using that drive letter.  Also, from Explorer, right click over the file and see what the permissions are.  If they are assigned to a specific user, I wonder if adding the Everyone group would help.
I tried looking at the manual, and the firmware release notes to see if this was a known problem that a firmware update fixed, however, I couldn't find any release notes, and the manuals didn't mention anything special for command prompts.